# Email validation show domain (.info) as invalid email

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, email

i'm creating a login system and i'm trying to validate email input. Validation is working just fine but there is a problem when the email is .info domain example(myemail@emailprovider.info), Which seems to be a valid domain, but the system mark it as invalid.Can you have a look please?

If you wondering about onkeypress event i'm using it to prevent empty spaces and on copy/paste as well.

This is the validation code

```js
$('#email').keyup(function () {
  if ($("#email").val().match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/)) {
  $("#emailmessage").html('Email is valid!');

 } else {
     $("#emailmessage").html('This is invalid email!');
  }

 });
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail..." id="email" name="email" onkeypress=" return event.keyCode || event.which, event.keyCode != 32 && event.which != 32" onpaste="return false;">
<div class="message" id="emailmessage"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here `\w{2,3}` you have it limited to only allow to 2 or 3 letters, change it to `\w{2,4}`

```js
$('#email').keyup(function() {
  if ($("#email").val().match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/)) {
    $("#emailmessage").html('Email is valid!');
  } else {
    $("#emailmessage").html('This is invalid email!');
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail..." id="email" name="email" onkeypress=" return event.keyCode || event.which, event.keyCode != 32 && event.which != 32" onpaste="return false;">
<div class="message" id="emailmessage"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an improved version of your code I've also removed jQuery

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const message = document.getElementById('emailmessage');

email.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  const validEmail = e.currentTarget.value.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/)
  message.textContent = validEmail ? 'Email is valid!' : 'This is invalid email!'
})

email.addEventListener('keypress', e => e.code === 'Space' && e.preventDefault())

email.addEventListener('paste', e => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail..." id="email" name="email">
<div class="message" id="emailmessage"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It working just fine, and the improved code is much better, the only reason for using jQuery is that i also make a live check if email exist in database via ajax request.

Comment: @popov I just saw that you have inline html event listeners, that shouldn't be used nowadays, I've updated the answer if you wanna take a look again :)

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you so much, i'm pretty new to JS and coding at all and this validations is killing me :D